# Project euler #10 getting wrong answer

Tags: java

The question in problem 10 in project euler states to add all primes below 2000,000. I tried other numbers and it worked fine but when I tried 2000,000 the answer is wrong. Why is that?  Here's my code.

```
Long number = scanner.nextLong();
Long sum = 17L;
for (Long i = 11L; i <= number; i ++) {
if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) {
} else {
sum += i;
}
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Your code only recognizes the first 4 primes. You will need to change the structure. You can use a `List` for the primes. When you know a number is prime, add it to the list and to check if a number is prime, check against the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prime-detection algorithm is completely wrong, It will work for (very small) primes but will fall over pretty fast after that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Why didn't it work on big numbers?

Comment: Because it was completely wrong! Read the link.

Comment: Yeah got it. It's indeed wrong XD thanks